# Problema ao extrair arquivo zip - ZipArchive

Tags: php

Eu criei um script para gerar um (***Backup/Restaurar***) arquivos em meu sistema, ele funciona perfeitamente em "local-*windows*" tanto o backup como a restauração, porém ao subir na "hospedagem-*linux*" acontece o seguinte.

1. Primeiro eu gero o backup local e subo na hospedagem.
2. na hospedagem eu restauro esse backup.

Só que ele pega o endereço dos arquivos e gera apenas um ficando assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em vez de criar as estruturas ele mescla tudo em um, *para ser ainda mais especifico veja na linha 3 na imagem, era para criar as pastas application | configuration | functions-groups e depois o arquivo Admin.php porem juntou tudo.*

**Obs**: se na hospedagem eu gerar o backup e restaurar ele funciona perfeitamente, se eu pegar um arquivo zip qualquer gerado "local" e subir também funciona na hospedagem.

não sei se vem ao caso mas a hospedagem é a *hostgator* e a versão do php em local/hospedagem é 7.3

**index.php**

```php
/*
Estrutura da pasta

raiz_do_site
-meusite.com
--systemRoot
---index.php
*/

define('INFO', array(
    //backup nome que vai ser gerado
    'backupName' => 'BACKUP', 

    //backup nome que vai após ser restaurado
    'restoreName' => 'RESTORED', 

    //nome da pasta para onde o arquivo será enviado após gerado o backup
    'destDir' => 'BackupFiles', 
));
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

function initBackup($source_path, $dir_skip = array()){

    $source_path = realpath($source_path);
    $backupName = INFO['backupName'].'_'.date('d_m_Y_-_H_i_s');

    if (!is_dir(__DIR__.DS.INFO['destDir'])) {
        mkdir(__DIR__.DS.INFO['destDir'], 0755);
    }

    $zip_file = __DIR__.DS.INFO['destDir'].DS.$backupName.'.zip';

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source_path),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {

       if (!$file->isDir()) {

        $file_path = $file->getRealPath();
        $file_view = explode('\\', $file_path);

        if(!array_intersect($dir_skip, $file_view)){
         $relative_path = substr($file_path, strlen($source_path) + 1);
         $zip->addFile($file_path, $relative_path);
     }
 }
}

$zip->close();
return $zip_file;
}

function initRestore($backupFile){

    $dir = __DIR__.DS.INFO['destDir'].DS;

    if (file_exists($dir.$backupFile)) {
        $path = pathinfo(realpath($dir.$backupFile), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
        $file_restore_name = INFO['restoreName'].'_'.date('d_m_Y__H_i_s').'.zip';

        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zip->open($dir.$backupFile);
        if ($res === TRUE) {
            $zip->extractTo('../');
            $zip->close();
        }
        rename($dir.$backupFile, $dir.$file_restore_name);

        $msg = 'Arquivo restaurado com sucesso';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Arquivo não encontrado';
    }

    echo $msg;
}
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GERA O BACKUP - initBackup($source_path, $dir_skip)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   $source_path = informe o diretório no qual o backup será realizado
|   $dir_skip = informe um array contendo as pasta que o backup não irá zipar
|
*/
 //initBackup('../', array('pasta1', 'pasta2','arquivo1.php','arquivo2.php'));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESTAURA O BACKUP - initRestore($backupFile, $location)
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   $backupFile = informe o backup que será restaurado
|   $location = informe o diretório que será restaurado
|
*/
//initRestore('BACKUP_29_10_2019_-_22_31_28.zip');
```

Comment: Parece-me que é um problema de como Windows e Linux tratam os caminhos(path). Em Windows com "\" e em Linux com "/".

Comment: o duro é que eu não sei onde posso mudar isso, com DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR resolveria mas onde?

Comment: Teria de verificar se está em ambiente windows ou linux e alterar o separador no restauro. Outra opção é fazer um backup para windows e outro para linux.